# Pass system date before open windows context menu

Tags: windows, context-menu

I did create an option in the windows context menu that calls a batch file to do a backup.
Someting like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Do backup]
@="&Do backup"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\shell32.dll,71"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Do backup\command]
@="E:\\Cgrama\\mmf.cmd \" \"%f\""
```

What I need now is, before opening the windows context menu, the system date is passed to the front of "Do backup", e.g., it will show something like "Do backup mm/dd/yyyy".

How can I accomplishe this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have dynamic titles with static registry-based menu items. (Of course, you can still have the backup script *itself* obtain the current date and use it as part of the backup label – just not for the menu item.)

Dynamic menu items would need a 'shell extension' .dll to be written (typically in C++), e.g. as documented [here](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2021/07/19/extending-the-context-menu-and-share-dialog-in-windows-11/)/[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers)/[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/support-legacy-context-menus). The [NileSoft shell](https://nilesoft.org/) app might let you achieve this using its scripting system.

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated!!

Comment: Also this line doesn't work: @="E:\\Cgrama\\mmf.cmd \" \"%f\"". What am I missing? The mmf.cmd batch is not executed!